# How to add jekyll build command in gulp watch task?

Tags: sass, gulp, jekyll

I need to run `jekyll build` during gulp watch task and I did that as per the following code.

```
var gulp = require('gulp-help')(require('gulp')),
    sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src(sassFiles)
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDest));
});

gulp.task('jekyll-build', function (done) {
    return cp.spawn(jekyll, ['build'], {stdio: 'inherit'})
        .on('close', done);
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass'], function(){
    gulp.watch(['_includes/**/*.js', '_includes/**/*._', 'assets/styles/**/*.scss'], ['jekyll-build', 'sass']);
});
```

When I make some changes in any file and try to save at once, command runs in terminal but it is not getting reflected in UI. I need to save twice or thrice to get the changes reflected. Not sure what's the issue or whether its the issue of the gulp watch code added here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you even using Gulp to compile your Sass? Jekyll can [do that by itself](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/assets).

Comment: I had to implement gulp as I had JS minification, uglification etc to be performed and I have to host this in GitHub. So I didn't use any Jekyll plugins or Jekyll in-build tasks.

Answer (score 1):

When you say the changes are not reflected do you mean the browser is not refreshing?

The line to launch jekyll build is different for mac vs Windows, your looks like it is for a Mac, on Windows I use `jekyll.bat` on this line `(jekyll, ['build']`.

In your watch step you are not watching very much. Rather than try to tell gulp to watch every different thing I do the opposite and tell gulp to watch everything `**/*.*` and then tell it what not to watch like `!_site/**/*`. This also lets you watch the config file for changes.

Also, it doesn't look like you are live-reloading with browser sync, that is half the fun of using gulp with jekyll (other half is having gulp do sass processing as it is much faster than jekyll).

Here is a gulp file that I use and a link to a write up I did about it:

https://rdyar.github.io/2017/10/01/speed-up-jekyll-by-using-gulp-for-sass-and-other-assets/

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var cp          = require('child_process');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var postcss    = require('gulp-postcss');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var cssnano = require('cssnano');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var htmlhint = require("gulp-htmlhint");

var messages = {
    jekyllBuild: '<span style="color: grey">Running:</span> $ jekyll build'
};
// Gulp as asset manager for jekyll. Please note that the assets folder is never cleaned
//so you might want to manually delete the _site/assets folder once in a while.
// this is because gulp will move files from the assets directory to _site/assets,
// but it will not remove them from _site/assets if you remove them from assets.

/**
 * Build the Jekyll Site - for windos. If you are on a Mac/linux change jekyll.bat to just jekyll
 */
gulp.task('jekyll-build', function (done) {
    browserSync.notify(messages.jekyllBuild);
    return cp.spawn('jekyll.bat', ['build'], {stdio: 'inherit'})
        .on('close', done);
});

/**
 * Rebuild Jekyll & do page reload when watched files change
 */
gulp.task('jekyll-rebuild', ['jekyll-build'], function () {
    browserSync.reload();
});

/**
 * Wait for jekyll-build, then launch the Server
 */

gulp.task('serve', ['jekyll-build'], function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: "_site/"
    });
});

/**
 * Watch jekyll source files for changes, don't watch assets
 */
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(['**/*.*', '!_site/**/*','!_assets/**/*','!node_modules/**/*','!.sass-cache/**/*' ], ['jekyll-rebuild']);
});

//watch just the sass files - no need to rebuild jekyll
gulp.task('watch-sass', ['sass-rebuild'], function() {
     gulp.watch(['_assets/sass/**/*.scss'], ['sass-rebuild']);
});

// watch just the js files
gulp.task('watch-js', ['js-rebuild'], function() {
     gulp.watch(['_assets/js/**/*.js'], ['js-rebuild']);
});

// watch just the image files
gulp.task('watch-images', ['images-rebuild'], function() {
     gulp.watch(['_assets/img/**/*.*'], ['images-rebuild']);
});

//if sass files change just rebuild them with gulp-sass and what not
gulp.task('sass-rebuild', function() {
     var plugins = [
        autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 2 version']}),
        cssnano()
    ];
     return gulp.src('_assets/sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(postcss(plugins))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe( gulp.dest('_site/assets/css/') )
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }))
});

gulp.task('js-rebuild', function(cb) {
    return gulp.src('_assets/js/**/*.js')
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe( gulp.dest('_site/assets/js/') )
      .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }))
});

gulp.task('images-rebuild', function(cb) {

     return gulp.src('_assets/img/**/*.*')
      .pipe( gulp.dest('_site/assets/img/') )
      .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }))
});

/**
 * Default task, running just `gulp` will 
 * compile the jekyll site, launch BrowserSync & watch files.
 */
gulp.task('default', ['serve', 'watch','watch-sass','watch-js','watch-images']);


//build and deploy stuff
gulp.task('imagemin', function() {
    console.log('Minimizing images in source!!');
 return gulp.src('_assets/img/**/*')
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(function (file) {
        return file.base;
    }));
});

gulp.task('w3', function() {
gulp.src("_site/**/*.html")
    .pipe(htmlhint())
    .pipe(htmlhint.reporter())
})
// validate from the command line instead, works better
// npm install htmlhint -g
// htmlhint _site/**/*.html
```

Comment: Also check out this article explaining how to migrate from gulp 3 to 4. I found this very useful: [how to migrate to gulp 4](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-migrate-to-gulp-4/)